# Can I use standardised coefficients in ordinal logistic and Poisson regressions?

Tags: standardization

I ran some OLS regressions with standardised coefficients, but to test the robustness of my results, I also want to run an ordinal logistic regression, as well as a Poisson model, using count data.

My dependent variable is a big ranking, which explains why I can use both OLS and ordinal regression (for the count model, I won't go much into details, but it is possible to use it if I tweak my dependent variable a bit). I can give more context if needed, but I think it would just add unnecessary details.

I want to be able to compare my coefficients across my three models, for this, I wanted to use standardised data for my ordinal and count models.

Can I do this ? Or is it not recommended to standardize data when the dependant variable is ordinal/count ?

Comment: You might find it helpful to write down how each model is interpreted.  Presumably, that would take the form "One unit increase in explanatory variable $X_j$ is associated with a [describe how the response changes and by how much and in what units of measurement]." Once you get that far it should either be apparent the two models just aren't comparable, or else you will have a clear indication of how to convert the coefficients of one into those of the other.